"Black headphone" takes guy to virtual reality game where he is in danger of dying in real life
Around 2006 I think, I watched this movie on TV, where a seemingly skeptical guy decided to play a game by using a kind of black headphone, which could take him to a virtual reality game (if I recall well it was a shooting game). The problem was, that thing was malfunctioning, and took him to a place where he felt the pain of the game for real, and was in danger of dying in real life as well. While playing the game, he finds a girl and another guy (one of them betrays him later). Most of his enemies looked mafia-like or military-like. 
The whole film went around a kind of dark city, with almost no lights on the street, and the group comes later into a type of yellow wasteland to fight. Other than a symbol representing the lifespan (a red glowing thing I think), the game itself is pretty real (no fantasy elements involved).
If it helps, the main guy was pretty young and had brown hair, and during the most part of the film is hurt in his arm (but it might have been his leg).
I really can't remember the rest of it, I may have mixed up some facts, but I am pretty sure this was a movie and must not be too older than 2000. Hope it is not too generic.
Edit: There is a cafe/bar that shows up two times in the film, with the main character and another person in it.    

Is it this movie http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stay_Alive

Is it Harsh Realm?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harsh_Realm

Unfortunately it is none of the above. It definitely seemed like an indie movie, in fact I can't even confirm it is american because it was dubbed in portuguese and the actors were not well known. I guess I just made it tougher...

Possibly Nirvana, eXistenZ (Longshot), or Virtuosity. In the last one (Virtuosity), they enter the virtual world through black headphones/eyemasks.

Nope, I checked all of those and some more and still couldn't find it. Starting to think it is indeed a foreign movie. By the way, the main character seemed to look like a mix of Callum Blue and Scott Clifton (I kinda thought one of them was him), if that helps in anything.

The film is Gamebox 1.0, from 2004. I found it by chance when searching for movies about technology going wrong. 
I mixed a lot of things up, specially the black headphone (which was actually a kind of silver helm), and the fact that the whole movie was in that dark city. He was actually in danger of life if he didn't complete the game. And I completely forgot the hallucinations in his real life.
Thanks for all the help, guys.
